# What is a name that can represent both a file or directory?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I am naming some variables in my code and I am trying to avoid naming things such as `nameOfFileOrFolder` or `pathOfFileOrFolder`. What is a good name or way to represent both of them? Does one exist?

For example:
A *girl* or *boy* can be both represented by the word **person**.
A *cat* or *dog*  can both be represented by the word **pet** or **animal** OR **mammal**.
A *file* or *directory* can both be represented by the word ....

Comment: Well.. In `java` both files and folder are referenced as a file..

Comment: Hmmm... I would also be printing some text that has contains "files or folders" ... Just wanted a word to identify them both in normal language, but thank you for that tidbit.

Comment: File system resource? File system object?

Comment: Why not just Path ? (it can point to a file or a folder)

Comment: Here is a related thread on the 'programmers' stackexchange.  [word-for-the-superset-of-files-and-folders](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/183856/word-for-the-superset-of-files-and-folders)  

I think that `File System` 'something' is the closest - i.e. `FileSystemEntry` or Object, Item - or `FSNode` as recommended in the link.

Comment: Thank you NSGaga, if you put that as your answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 14):

The Software Engineering Stack Exchange has a good discussion about this:

[Word for the superset of files and folders - Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/183856/word-for-the-superset-of-files-and-folders)

You could call it `FileSystemEntry`, `FileSystemObject`, `FileSystemNode` or `FSNode`.

Answer (score 5):

I usually just call it `path`

- `configPath` could mean a file or folder and is generic
- `configFilePath` can be specific to files
- `configDirPath` can be specific to folders

Comment: The problem with calling it a path is that that normally refers to a complete path, e.g. '/var/tmp/whatever.txt'. When talking about just 'whatever.txt' you're not really talking about a path, you're just talking about an entry. That's why I prefer @OCDev's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Dart uses `FileSystemEntity` for such case. Reference
[here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-io/FileSystemEntity-class.html).